# EEPROM Esp8266 Memory Issue

Tags: esp8266, eeprom

I had assembled a board with esp8266ex bare chip with 4MB eeprom for esp and also can be shared with host MCU. I had gone through some googling and found that using eeprom function I am able to write data in eeprom using esp8266ex. But I had seen the limitation of 4KB. Then I had researched more than I found that there is a way to increase that.

So my question is, Is there are any issue if I changed that 4KB to 2 MB or more in esp8266 library?

I am using arduino IDE for Esp programming.

Comment: eeprom or flash? only 4kB can be used for EEPROM emulation in esp8266 flash memory layout

Comment: flash. I am asking if what will happen if I increase the 4KB to 2MB.

Comment: use SPIFFS file system. it can use to 3MB of 4MB. https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html

Comment: I tried the spiffs, every time it shows unable to find file, but the file path is right and even the file name.

Comment: try more. try the examples. it works.

Comment: ok I will check tomorrow for another example for spiffs.

Comment: the basic example is called ConfigFile and FSBrowser is a complex example

Comment: Actually I tried the basic example in which it will go to the directory, open the file and try to print the file data on serial monitor. But I always for the result as Unable to open the file.

Comment: yes. the example is wrong. it expects the SPIFFS initialized. read the doc on the link few comments above